# Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android in Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I know there are lot of questions like this in stack overflow, but i want know at this present date, still this problem did't solved ?

I saw [this document](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android)  for Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android and i tried it in my   Ubuntu 12.4.

when i run this command `sencha package run android.json` in terminal, I got

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[ERR] stbuild is not yet supported on linux
```

Then i searched and i come to that **"Native packaging is not yet supported on Linux, only OS X and Windows at the moment."**

1) [related forum in sencha](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242390-2.1-beta3-sencha-generate-app-filed-on-linux64)

2) [related forum in sencha](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?193336-Error-while-building-native-application-in-Linux&p=772801)

**my environment is Ubuntu 12.4, is there any solution? or i need to change environment (windows or mac environment).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though, I havent heard about any official notification of release of Native Packaging for Sencha Touch 2 in Linux, but a guy claims to make it work in one of his posts, you can have a look at it,

[Sencha 2 Command for Linux](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185783-Sencha-2-command-for-Linux&p=752927&viewfull=1#post752927).  However it is for `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS`

Comment: I did exactly same as posted, every thing gone fine, now i ran the same command `sencha package run android.json` now i got  `[ERROR] /bin/sh: 1: stbuild: not found`

Comment: Ok, i continued to see full thread, many of them got the same error and i can't find solution just like them.

Comment: @Viswa : The code is quite tricky, though I havent worked on it. But I dont think there might be any way to use it on Linux.

Comment: Yes, its always a better option. Though we can hope of release of linux version soon.